# Typeahead input validation

Tags: jquery, validation, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I want to use Typeahead in a way that its data are prefetched from the server like the Prefetch example in http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/.

My concern is how I could validate the user input in the client before sending it to the server since it seems I do not have any access to the data downloaded from the server. Typeahead and Bloodhound documentation do not give any tip about that.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the Bloodhound object with Chrome's help, it is easy to see that

```
bloodhound.index.datums
```

is the array of the options you receive from the server when Bloodhound is configured with a 'prefetch' field on it. I have not evaluated the case when the 'remote' option is configured during Bloohound initialization, but I'd consider a different behaviour very very weird.